# remove blank line in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

i have looked at multiple question posts and im wondering how to get rid of the last line of a file, or to say, a blank line

```
infile = open("milkin.txt","r").readlines()   
outfile = open("milkout.txt","w")                                                           

number = infile[0]                            
arrayLoc = infile[1].split( )                 
array = infile[2].split( )                                                                  

dictionary = {}                                                                             

for i, z in zip(arrayLoc, array):             
    dictionary[i] = z                         

for key in sorted(dictionary):                
    outfile.write(dictionary[key])            
    outfile.write("\n")
```

---

```
outfile:
5520059
8089172
7180540
6513926
9202362
2641421
2897763
2383426
1490027
1368690
```

there is an extra line below the numbers, and i want to remove it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.join` with a generator expression instead to avoid the trailing newline:

Change:

```
for key in sorted(dictionary):                
    outfile.write(dictionary[key])            
    outfile.write("\n")
```

To:

```
outfile.write('\n'.join(dictionary[key] for key in sorted(dictionary)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is here:

```
outfile.write("\n")
```

This should do:

```
newline = ''
for key in sorted(dictionary):
    outfile.write(newline)
    outfile.write(dictionary[key])
    newline = '\n'
```

You won't have the blank line at the start of the file since `newline` is initialized as an empty string.

Comment: This adds a blank line at the beginning of the file.

Comment: thank you, but this creates the opposite problem. the blank line appears at the top of the outfile now.

Comment: I've edited my answer after debugging the code, this should work now! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's an improved version of @jsub's answer:

```
for line, key in enumerate(sorted(dictionary)):   
    if line: # Do not do for line #0!
        outfile.write("\n")               
    outfile.write(dictionary[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
infile = open("milkin.txt","r").readlines()   
outfile = open("milkout.txt","w")                                                           

number = infile[0]                            
arrayLoc = infile[1].split( )                 
array = infile[2].split( )                                                                  

dictionary = {}                                                                             

for i, z in zip(arrayLoc, array):             
    dictionary[i] = z                         

for key in sorted(dictionary):                
    outfile.write(dictionary[key])            
    outfile.write("\n")
outfile.writelines([dictionary[key] if list(sorted(dictionary))[-1]==key else dictionary[key]+'\n' for idx,key in enumerate(sorted(dictionary))])
```